# Display inline block issues

Tags: html, css

I have a two divs aligned side to side and they work as I want them on desktop but when it comes to mobile browser (it works on chrome mobile as the desktop one) like Mozilla Firefox, Safari one of the divs push to the bottom. I have tried setting overflow:scroll to the div container but that doesn't solve the prob. Can someone help me out?

**css**

```
.container{
    margin: 10px  auto 20px auto;
    display:table;
   overflow:scroll;
} 

.left_col{
    width: 700px;
    border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#fff;
    vertical-align:top;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}

.right_col{
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    height:1090px;
    background-color:#fff;
    vertical-align:top;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class=left_col"></div>
    <div class="right_col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If two elements are inline, when there is no more horizontal space, it will simply move the last element to the next line.

Comment: @Ibu what about overflow: scroll then?

Comment: @Lmxc - `overflow:scroll` won't work because nothing is overflowing. By flowing the last element on to the next line, everything will fit in the container div.

Answer (score 1):

Your viewport isn't sufficiently wide on a mobile browser to fix 1000px of content. Consider using percentage widths if you want to maintain that layout.

```
.left_col{
    width: 70%;
    float:left;
}

.right_col{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: +1 You should also add max-width:1000px; width:100% to the container it should make it pretty flexible! :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution will be to move set a width on the parent if possible.

```
.container{
   ...
   width:1024px;
} 

.left_col{
    width: 700px;
    float:left;
}

.right_col{
    width:300px;
    float:left;
}
```